# 5GbE over fiber optic cable with SFP+

Tags: layer1, cable, fiber, sfp, transceiver

I have to build a 5GbE link with a SFP+. Can i use the one that is rated for 8Gbps? And what kind of NIC should I use on host PC?

Answer (score 2):

Both 5 Gbps and 8 Gbps are non-standard ethernet speeds, and you won't find those speeds on SFP+s. In fact, you will not find 8 Gbps ethernet at all. If you are using fiber, you will get 10 Gbps, but you must make sure of the fiber and length, which must match the SPF+, which must also match the SFP+ on the other end. Some copper SFP+s can also do 1 Gbps (possibly 100 Mbps and 10 Mbps), besides 10 Gbps.

Some switches from members of the  NBASE-T Alliance have ports which can do 2.5  or 5 Gbps, besides the standard 10 or 100 Mbps, and 1 or 10 Gbps.

It is unlikely that you will find a host NIC that can do either 5 or 8 Gbps. There are server NICs which can do 10 Gbps.

Comment: That's bad news... So i will need a switch to get 5GbE and the 10GbE link to the host?

Comment: If you need 5 Gbps, then you should just get 10 Gbps gear. That will let you run up to 10 Gbps. I don't understand the need to limit it to 5 Gbps. You could always do policing to limit a 10 Gbps connection to 5 Gbps.

Comment: I have hardware with 6.6Gbps transceivers. Going to 10Gbps costs to much for the system and requires development cycle that i am not sure i can afford.

Comment: There are no ethernet 6.6 Gbps transceivers. You have something else.

Comment: It's a generic transceiver. I use Zynq7030. It can be configured to ethernet or anything else.

Comment: It's not ethernet. The IEEE creates the ethernet standards, and there is no 6.6 Gbps ethernet. You have something else.

Comment: I have a transceiver that can go up to 6.6gbps. This is why i am limited to 5GbE.

Comment: @GregoryKornblum, according to that part specification, it has "_Support for Gigabit Ethernet (PHY)_," which is 1 Gbps ethernet. Your transceiver is not an ethernet transceiver because it doesn't match any ethernet standard, and it will not interoperate with any that do. You seem to be on the wrong site. You should probably ask this on [Electrical Engineering](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/), not a site for "_asking questions about professionally managed networks in a business environment._"

Comment: Phy support is GMII interface and MAC, i am not talking about it. Please just trust me, MAC can be built in the PL side of the component and run ethernet through the transceiver. Let's assume it is a fact. Can you please answer me about the switch? Or even recommend such a switch?

Comment: You don't understand, there is no ethernet which runs at the speed you are asking about. It is possible that you could get this to work between two of these things, but it will not interoperate with anything else. Ethernet is a series of layer-1/2 standards, and none are what you seek. The proposed 5 Gbps standard is over copper, not fiber, in order to provide 802.11ac WAPs  with enough bandwidth. There is no such thing as 5 Gbps ethernet over fiber. This is off-topic for this site.

Comment: Ok, so if i would use copper instead fiber you would answer? I mean, it's not a big deal to go to copper...

Comment: At this point in time, you would need to contact the NBASE-T alliance to get in on their program. There are currently no NICs which do this. You would be limited to a few switches and WAPs, but you would need to adhere to the specifications which the alliance is proposing for IEEE certification. That would also be off-topic here. This is not a development site. "_Network Engineering Stack Exchange is for asking questions about professionally managed networks in a business environment._"